# How is the SceneDelegate available through @EnvironmentObject

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm setting delegate class for UISceneConfiguration like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession,
                 options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    let sceneConfig = UISceneConfiguration(name: nil, sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    sceneConfig.delegateClass = SceneDelegate.self
    return sceneConfig
}
```

My body of the @main App is

```
var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootView()
        }
}
```

How is the sceneDelegate object available in the RootView by?

```
struct RootView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var sceneDelegate: SceneDelegate
[...]
}
```

I don't understand who and where is setting this object.

Comment: I mean, the sceneDelegate is available - and I don't know why.

Comment: It is part of the setup performed by the code created by `@main`.